# prove that $f(t)$ is orthogonal to $f'(t)$ for som all $t \in I$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, orthogonal-polynomials

Suppose that $I$ is nonempty open interval and that $f: I \to \Bbb R^m$ is differentiable on $I$

If $f(I) \subseteq \partial B_r(0) $ for some fixed $r>0$, prove that $f(t)$ is orthogonal to $f'(t)$ for som all $t \in I$

I guess I need to use the chain rule. Sorry, I cannot say any idea about the question.

But what is orthogonal?

How can I link between orhogonal and the chain rule of partial derivatives ?

I am glad to show me the proof step by step. Thanks for helping:)

Comment: How? Pls Explain more.. @user46080

Comment: The norm of $f$ is constant. So $f\cdot f=C$ for some constant $C$. Differentiate both sides of this equation.

Comment: Why constant? Can you write the solution way on below answer part by explaining in detail and step by step if you mind? Please.. @DavidMitra

Comment: $\Vert f(x)\Vert=r$ for all $x\in I$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit** I am just adding some details to the approach suggested by @David Mitra in the above comments.

Hint: by definition,

$$f(t)=(x(t),y(t))$$

with $x^2(t)+y^2(t)=r^2$ for all $t\in I$. The trick, as pointed out by @David Mitra is to note that

$$\|f(t)\|^2=x^2(t)+y^2(t)=r^2,$$

i.e. $\|f(t)\|$ is constant for all $t\in I$. Try now to compute the derivative

$$\frac{d}{dt}\|f(t)\|^2 $$

using the definition of $\|f(t)\|^2$. You should arrive at

$$\frac{d}{dt}\|f(t)\|^2=2\langle f(t),f'(t)\rangle,$$

where $f'(t)=(x'(t),y'(t))$. This is sufficient to finish the problem (why?).

Comment: That's, the last equation is equal to $2f(t)+Df(t)$ Is it? It is sufficient because you have shown that its inner products are differentiable. Right? @Avitus

Comment: If $\|f(t)\|^2=r^2$ is constant, what is $\frac{d}{dt}\|f(t)\|^2=$?

Comment: This is equal to Zero

Comment: Exactly: $0=\langle f, f'\rangle$. What does it geometrically mean?

Comment: Inner productor like that.. I forgot linear algebra a little bit:(

Comment: For all $t\in I$, $f(t)$ and $f'(t)$ are vectors in $\mathbb R^2$. The equation $0=\langle f,f'\rangle$ is equivalent to state that $f(t)$ and $f'(t)$ are orthogonal...you are done :-)

Comment: this means orthogonal. I remember:) thank you. You teach very well:) thank you:)

Comment: you are welcome!